# Jquery ajax xml is not being parsed

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml-parsing

So I was parsing my xml with this code and all worked fine untill i added a review node.

```
$(document).ready(function generatexml(){
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "data/concerts.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml){
                $(xml).find("concert").each(function(){
                $('#concerten').append('<div id="tabel" onclick="navigate('+"'"+$(this).find('artist').text()+"'"+')"><div id="tabelimage"><img src="http://griekenland.mixxt.at/storage/images/events/0/0/0/00000000000000000000000000000.jpg"/></div>'
                +'<div id="tabelartist">'+$(this).find('artist').text()+'</div>'
                +'<div id="tabellocation">'+$(this).find('location').text()+'</div>'
                +'<div id="tabelqs">'+$(this).find('review').text()+'</div>'
                +'<div id="tabeldate">'+$(this).find('date').text()+'</div>'
                +'<div id="tabelurl"><a href="'+$(this).find('url').text()+'">'+$(this).find('url').text()+'</a></div>').trigger('create');             
                })
                }
                })
})
```

The xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<concerts>
<concert>
<artist>Sioen</artist>
<location>De Zwerver leffinge</location>
<date>24/03/2012</date>
<review>Met die woorden, op zelf getekende en verspreide flyers, riep Willis Earl Beal iedereen op hem te bellen om hem één van z’n liedjes te horen zingen</review>
<url>http://www.test.be</url>
</concert>
<concert>
<artist>Sioen</artist>
<location>De Zwerver leffinge</location>
<date>24/03/2012</date>
<review>Met die woorden, op zelf getekende en verspreide flyers, riep Willis Earl Beal iedereen op hem te bellen om hem één van z’n liedjes te horen zingen</review>
<url>http://www.test.be</url>
</concert>
</concerts>
```

I cannot figure out the reason why it won't parse, i have ran it trough an xml validator and there are no js errors in firebug. Is it possible that the text inside my node is to long (just a hunch) and how do i counter this?

Any help is welcome,
Tyvm

Toon Van Dooren

Comment: You should not use `onclick` attributes at all. Also, your code would create multiple elements with the same ID (`"tabel"`). This is not allowed in HTML.

Comment: Both worked fine untill i added the review tag tough, i am using the onclick because i was planning to make the review string shorter and use a detail page, this page is going to be a summary page :) *edit* I have removed the onclick and the ids on the divs and still have the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your particular issue but I think it could be useful.

I think you should consider using some template engine here. Here is why:

- Forces you to prepare/parse your data before rendering
- Allows you to unit test every single part independently
- Improves code readability and maintainability
- Easier to update later (for example if you decide to return JSON instead of XML in your AJAX request)

Please consider the following [example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/idobic/8/edit) based on your code (and using [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) template engine but you can find many other engines).

Some details bellow:

#### 1- define your template

```
<script id="concertsTpl" type="text/x-custom-tpl">
{{#concerts}}
  <div id="tabel" onclick="navigate('{{artist}}')">
    <div id="tabelimage">
      <img src="http://griekenland.mixxt.at/storage/images/events/0/0/0/00000000000000000000000000000.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="tabelartist">{{artist}}</div>
    <div id="tabellocation">{{location}}</div>
    <div id="tabelqs">{{review}}</div>
    <div id="tabeldate">{{date}}</div>
    <div id="tabelurl">
      <a href="{{url}}">{{url}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/concerts}}
</script>
```

#### 2- define a function to parse your data

```
function parseConcertsData(data) {
  var concerts = [];

  $(data).find("concert").each(function(){
    var concert = {
        artist: $(this).find('artist').text(),
      location: $(this).find('location').text(),
        review: $(this).find('review').text(),
          date: $(this).find('date').text(),
           url: $(this).find('url').text()
    };
    concerts.push(concert);
  });
  return {concerts: concerts};
}
```

#### 3- send the request and process the result

```
var jqXhr = $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
       url: "data/concerts.xml",
  dataType: 'xml'
});

jqXhr.done(function(xml){

  var concerts = parseConcertsData(xml),
      tpl = $('#concertsTpl').html(),
      rendered = Mustache.to_html(tpl, concerts);

  $('#concerten').append( rendered ).trigger('create');

}).fail(function(){
  alert('Something went wrong with the query');
});
```

With this kind of refactoring, you should be able to find the problem easily:

- Do you receive a response from your query?
- Do you get the expected data (ie: Is the response parsed correctly)?
- Is the template rendering OK?
- Is the rendered template appended to the document?

Hope it helps.

---

Comment: Will try this asap and let u know ty

Comment: More structured and working, tyvm. Tough I am still going to try to find what I have done wrong :p

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what wrong in your code neither. Everything worked fine when I wrote the jsbin from your code. jQuery version maybe?

Comment: hmz could be :)  ill try a diffo version